# "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue." while trying to invoke a new Dialog

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I can't seem to be able to add another Dialog to the Dialog Stack in the BotFramework. I created a small bot application using the [c# template found here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.BotBuilderV3).

I only changed the RootDialog code to this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

namespace TextBot.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Welcome! This is the root dialog.");
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;

            if (activity.Text == "other") context.Call<string>(new EchoDialog(), this.MessageReceivedAsync);

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class EchoDialog : IDialog<string>
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Hi there, this is Another dialog!");
            context.Done(true);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try this code out using the BotEmulator, this is what the conversation looks like:

> Me: Hi!
>   Bot: Welcome! This is the root dialog.
>   Me: other
>   Bot: Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.

This is what the output in the debug console looks like:

> iisexpress.exe Warning: 0 : Service url localhost:51528 is not trusted and JwtToken cannot be sent to it.
>   Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.InvalidNeedException' in Microsoft.Bot.Builder.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.InvalidNeedException' in mscorlib.dll
>   iisexpress.exe Warning: 0 : Service url localhost:51528 is not trusted and JwtToken cannot be sent to it.
>   Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.InvalidNeedException' in mscorlib.dll
>   The thread 0x3c9c has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I have no clue what I am doing wrong. Can someone please tell me how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not far off. A couple of things to change:

1. You are using the MessageReceivedAsync method as the callback from the child dialog. Create a dedicated method to handle this callback. I've called this AfterChildDialogIsDone.
2. You are always calling context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync). You should only do this if you are not handing off to a child dialog. I've added an ELSE block to your IF to ensure that you only do this when intended.

```js
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

namespace TextBot.Dialogs {
  [Serializable]
  public class RootDialog: IDialog {
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context) {
      await context.PostAsync("Welcome! This is the root dialog.");
      context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable result) {
      var activity = await result as Activity;

      if (activity.Text == "other") {
        context.Call(new EchoDialog(), this.AfterChildDialogIsDone);
      } else {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
      }
    }

    private async Task AfterChildDialogIsDone(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable result) {
      context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
  }

  [Serializable]
  public class EchoDialog: IDialog {
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context) {
      await context.PostAsync("Hi there, this is Another dialog!");
      context.Done(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This did it for me, thank you! I lost half a day just because I always called `context.Wait`. Thank you!